# Rails Play MP4 on iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, html5-video, mobile-safari

I have an `.mp4` that I want to play on my site via the `video_tag` like so:

```
<%= video_tag "video1.mp4", type: "video/mp4" %>
```

This works on Firefox and Safari (on Mac) and on Android Chrome, but it doesn't work on Safari for iOS. Is there some special command or option to be able to view `.mp4` on an iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play mp4 on IOS mp4 encoding setting should be changed according to IOS requirements.

Actually not all encoded Mp4 files are supported by iPhone. Different encoding may cause some file to work and fail for others.

Best possible encoding settings are

1. Only use the H.264 Baseline
2. Profile Level 3.0
3. Resolution below 640 x 480 and framerate up to 30 fps
4. bitrate limit of 900kb.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a good sample iPad compatible mp4? Because I can't find one that would just work.

Comment: For mp4 to be played on ipad following settings are needed 
MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio

You can use FFMPEG https://www.ffmpeg.org/ to covert or change file settings. You can covert the mp4 file to any other format that is supported on ipad or you can change the mp4 settings to make it work on ipad.